# Ubuntu install both 'feh' and 'slack' ( libcurl3/4)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, curl, slack

OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

I've installed **slack** via [the `.deb` download](https://slack.com/downloads/linux).

I also want to install `feh`, [the image viewer](https://feh.finalrewind.org/)

```
$ sudo apt install feh
```

Results in:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl4
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libcurl3 slack-desktop
```

I'm guessing that **slack** is being uninstalled because it depends upon `libcurl3`.

What are my options to have both installed?

Alternatively, is there an equal / better image viewer I could use for scripting purposes?

---

**UPDATE**

Attempting to following the "build from source" instructions for `feh`, this response confirms that `libcurl` is the problem library:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcurl4
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libcurl3 slack-desktop
```

I don't know the differences between `libcurl3` and `libcurl4`. Is there anyway to make them play nicely togther?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, I just installed feh manually from the deb hosted on https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/feh/download and allowed me to have both installed.

Comment: And I compiled curl from source, so now I have it all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This reply from Slack support on Mon 23 April 2018:

My question:

> How can I build (compile) or acquire a version of Slack built with libcurl4 instead of libcurl3 ?
>   It basically means I can't install both curl and slack, yet curl is what you recommend in your API tutorial.
>   https://api.slack.com/tutorials/slack-apps-hello-world

Reply:

> Thanks for writing in to flag this! The slack-deskop deb requires libcurl3 right now even though libcurl4 should be fine. We have a fix for this dependency issue ready to be released with version 3.2.0, and I can let you know when that happens. In the meantime, you should be able to install the snap package instead: https://slack.com/downloads/linux.

---

A further update from Slack support on Mon 18 June 2018:

> Thanks again for taking the time to report this dependency issue with libcurl. We've released a fix for this problem, and you shouldn't run into it going forward on the latest version of the app. Let me know if you notice anything amiss!